# How to detect Member group change in SilverStripe 4

Tags: silverstripe-4

I have a `DataExtension` for Member, `MyMemberExtension`.

I'm trying to detect a user being moved from a `pending-users` group to a `public-users` group using onBeforeWrite and onAfterWrite in `MyMemberExtension`.
However the group change seems to happen before the onBeforeWrite here.

In `MyMemberExtension` I added an `$IsPending` class member.

```
public function onBeforeWrite()
{
    if ($this->owner->inGroup('pending-users'))
    {
        self::$isPending = true;
    }
}
```

and

```
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    if ($this->owner->inGroup('public-users') and self::$isPending)
    {
        # Moved from the pending to public - send email
    }
}
```

I also tried using `$this->owner->getChangedFields();` but Groups isn't part of the array.

How am I able to detect a user changing from `pending-users` to `public-users`?

Comment: The silverstripe-auditor module monitors for changes like this, it may be of some use: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-auditor/blob/2/code/AuditHookMemberGroupSet.php

Comment: @RobbieAverill thanks I'll check that out. Is what I've described expected behaviour?

Comment: The static property you're setting won't reset between members, because extensions are loaded as singletons by default. That might be contributing to your issue. Check out the docs for changing that here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/changelogs/4.0.0/#extensions-singletons